# Is it safe to install drivers for 14.04 LTS on 16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers

I upgraded my HP Z230 from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.
HP [provides](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5367828&swItemId=wk_139204_1&swEnvOid=4186) drivers for 14.04, but not for 16.04. Is it safe to install the drivers for 14.04?

Comment: In worst case scenario, you could go ahead and install the driver, but it might not work anyway, according to this site: http://www.howtogeek.com/213488/how-to-install-hardware-drivers-on-linux/ . However, if you happen to also have problems with an AMD graphic card, then the driver for this on Ubuntu 16.04 is not available yet.

Comment: As Xenial is still relatively new, maybe HP is working on the drivers and they will release it, if your computer is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Software and Updates' in Ubuntu to install necessary drivers, just select the 'Additional Drivers' tab, let it scan, and if there are drivers that need to be installed, click 'Apply Changes'.

Comment: I did. However, my wifi (connecting with a usb device) signal strength keeps jumping every few seconds between perfect and zero. So, I figured that may be I am still not using the right drivers or firmware...

Comment: Sorry for late response, can you tell us what is that wifi usb device?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly I can tell you about it. Is there a command I can run in the terminal and post the output?

Comment: It might also be a hardware problem. Have you tried that wifi usb on another computer?

Comment: This same usb worked just before the update and for at least a year before that. It would be too coincidental that it broke precisely when I updated to 16.04...

Comment: One potential problem with upgrading between versions, as stated by many, is that old packages may be left not upgraded to match the new version's requirements. That's why I decided to install 16.04 from scratch, instead of upgrading from 14.04. However, maybe you have spend time setting up your new system, reinstalling might be quite heart-rending...

Comment: Oh, I did not know one could update to another LTS not from scratch. Yes, my installation was from scratch.

Comment: Well there's a guide on OMG Ubuntu. Anyway, your problem might also be that the driver for your usb is proprietary and the manufacturer didn't want to or haven't provided it to the community. Or it might be a potential bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. So, can I use the driver for 14.04 LTS?

Comment: You can try, but according to the link I've share on the comment just under your question, there's no guarantee that it will work.

Comment: If it does not work, how bad a damage can happen? Does this try call for a complete system backup?

Comment: As I haven't found any complaint about a broken system because of old driver, I don't think it would be an issue. But if you are still worried, then maybe restoring a backup wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Btw, have you checked if the drivers you get from HP and Additional Drivers are the same? If they are, then you can be sure that your machine would be fine if you uninstall the driver.

Comment: UPDATE: http://askubuntu.com/a/790517/111162